# OpenSSL alert number 40

Tags: openssl

A program I've been using for years to read my email stopped working when my provider updated their servers. Now, when I run my program, I get this failure when I call `BIO_do_connect()`:

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1086:SSL alert number 40
```

The failure is identical under MacOS Yosemite and an old Linux distro.

By comparison, this command does *not* fail:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.example.org:993
```

For reference, here's a minimal program that demonstrates the problem (I've obscured my server name).

Is there some parameter I'm missing?

```
/*
 * Under MacOS, compile with:
 * cc -o tester -I/opt/local/include tester.c -L/opt/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto
 *
 * Under Linux, compile with:
 * cc -o tester tester.c -lssl
 */

#define CERTS_DIR       "/etc/ssl/certs/"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int
main()
{
    BIO *bio, *rbio;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    const char *hostname = "mail.example.org";
    int port = 993;

    SSL_library_init();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_client_method());
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return 3;
    }

    /* load trusted certs with SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()? */
    if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, CERTS_DIR)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to load trusted SSL certs\n");
    }

    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, hostname);
    BIO_set_conn_int_port(bio, &port);

    // Here is the call that fails
    if (BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot connect to %s:%d\n", hostname, port);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 3;
    }

    printf("Success\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of trial and error, I was able to make the problem go away by changing `SSLv3_client_method()` to `SSLv23_client_method()`